# How to open two pages from one link with JavaScript/ jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I am wondering if i can open `http://example.com/some-page` (clasic href link) in the same page that is viewed and the second link in a new tab.

```
<a href="http://example.com/some-page" second-url="http://example.com/other-page">link name</a>
```

I didn't found anything related to this on SO.

Is there a way to do it?

PS:

Please don't consider this a duplicate. The problem is that I will have multiple dynamic links (from DB) on a page. Can't add javascript for each link (this was the solution from other questions).

Comment: AFAICT, there's no non-JS solution...

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `window.open()`. You also need to call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default action of the `a` tag.

```
<a href="#">Click Here</a>

$('a').on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com');
    window.open('http://www.espn.com');
});
```

Here is an example fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/299tvrp9/

Comment: Thanks but I will have multiple dynamic links (from DB) on a page. Can't add javascript for each link.

Comment: `<a class="multilink" data-link1="http://www.link1.com" data-link2="http://www.link2.com">Text</a>` in your javascript `$(".multilink").click(function() { window.open($(this).attr("data-link1"), "_blank"); window.open($(this).attr("data-link2"), "_blank"); });` should do the trick (minus typos)

Answer (score 2):

You could do a one-liner:

```
<a href="http://example.com/some-page" onclick="window.open('http://example.com/other-page')">link name</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, the code works but the problem is when i click it, it pushes me in a new tab ( onclick window.open link) and i need to remain on the same page and the second link to open in another tab.

Comment: @m3tsys - You can't change the browser's preference of what the browser focuses when opening a new tab.

Comment: The problem is that i will need to keep `href` with the first link for seo purposes.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<a id="link-title">link name</a>
```

jQuery

```
$('#link-title').on('click', function(){
    window.open('https://linkaddress.com','_blank');
    window.open('https://linkaddresstwo.com','_blank');
});
```

Is that what you mean??

Comment: No need for the `_blank`, because it automatically opens in a new tab. Check my fiddle

Comment: cool, thanks for the info. Preferring @j08691 answer though

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've edited my question. Can you please check it?

Comment: Looks good to me mate